# How to Sign with RSA private key by CNG

Tags: c++, cryptography, rsa, cng

**1. How to sign with RSA private key?** (**SOLVED**)

I followed this [sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/seccng/signing-data-with-cng) to sign data with private key. I only reserve hash and sign functions, and use ECDSA P-256 private key like the sample.

Here are my steps and the program work fine:

- `BCryptOpenAlgorithmProvider()`
- Hash some data
- `NCryptOpenStorageProvider()`
- `NCryptCreatePersistedKey()`
- `NCryptFinalizeKey()`
- `NCryptSignHash()`
- `NCryptSignHash()`

I tried to sign with RSA private key, replace `NCRYPT_ECDSA_P256_ALGORITHM` with `NCRYPT_RSA_ALGORITHM` and `NCRYPT_RSA_SIGN_ALGORITHM`, but it failed in second `NCryptSignHash()` with `NTE_INVALID_PARAMETER`.

```
    //create a persisted key
    if (FAILED(secStatus = NCryptCreatePersistedKey(
        hProv,
        &hKey,
        NCRYPT_RSA_ALGORITHM,
        L"my RSA key",
        0,
        0)))
    {
        wprintf(L"**** Error 0x%x returned by NCryptCreatePersistedKey\n", secStatus);
        goto Cleanup;
    }
```

**2. Why the program can't find the private key after first run?**

The private key is created in the program, I tried to sign with X509 certificate which has private key(ECDSA P-256) in `My` certifacate store.

Here are my steps and **the program only work in the first run.** It failed in `CryptAcquireCertificatePrivateKey()` with `NTE_BAD_KEYSET error`

- `BCryptOpenAlgorithmProvider()`
- Hash some data
- `CertOpenStore()`
- `CertFindCertificateInStore()`
- `CryptAcquireCertificatePrivateKey()`
- `NCryptSignHash()`
- `NCryptSignHash()`

```
   // Open the certificate store.
   if (!(hCertStore = CertOpenStore(
       CERT_STORE_PROV_SYSTEM,
       0,
       NULL,
       CERT_SYSTEM_STORE_CURRENT_USER,
       CERT_STORE_NAME)))
   {
       MyHandleError(const_cast<LPTSTR>("The MY store could not be opened."));
   }
   swprintf(wMY_SIGNER_NAME, 100, L"%hs", MY_SIGNER_NAME);
   if (pSignerCert = CertFindCertificateInStore(
       hCertStore,
       MY_ENCODING_TYPE,
       0,
       CERT_FIND_SUBJECT_STR,
       wMY_SIGNER_NAME,
       NULL))
   {
       //_tprintf(TEXT("The signer's certificate was found.\n"));
   }
   else
   {
       MyHandleError(const_cast<LPTSTR>("Signer certificate not found."));
   }

   if (CryptAcquireCertificatePrivateKey(
       pSignerCert, 
       CRYPT_ACQUIRE_PREFER_NCRYPT_KEY_FLAG, NULL, 
       &hKey,
       &dwKeySpec, 
       false))
   {
       printf("Get Priv OK\n");
   }
   else
   {
       if (GetLastError() == NTE_BAD_KEYSET)
           printf("NTE_BAD_KEYSET\n");
   }
```

**UPDATE:**

```
    if (FAILED(secStatus = NCryptSignHash(
        hKey,
        0,
        pbHash,
        cbHash,
        NULL,
        0,
        &cbSignature,
        0)))
    {
        wprintf(L"**** Error 0x%x returned by NCryptSignHash1\n", secStatus);
        goto Cleanup;
    }

    //allocate the signature buffer
    pbSignature = (PBYTE)HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), 0, cbSignature);
    if (NULL == pbSignature)
    {
        wprintf(L"**** memory allocation failed\n");
        goto Cleanup;
    }

    if (FAILED(secStatus = NCryptSignHash(
        hKey,
        0,
        pbHash,
        cbHash,
        pbSignature,
        cbSignature,
        &cbSignature,
        0)))
    {
        wprintf(L"**** Error 0x%x returned by NCryptSignHash2\n", secStatus);
        goto Cleanup;
    }
```

**UPDATE2:**

The code work after removing `NCryptDeleteKey(hKey, 0)`. I think this API delete my EC key! But I don't know why RSA key not be deleted?

Comment: You open the algorithm provider but you don't close it. Could you try to skip the "open" call after the first run? The store probably can be kept open as well and once you've found your certificate / key pair, then that can also be cached.

Comment: For the rest it is unclear where you go wrong, you need to post your code. Replace `BCRYPT_SHA256_ALGORITHM` with `BCRYPT_RSA_ALGORITHM` can certainly not be right, RSA signature generation requires a hash.

Comment: Hi Maarten, I ran the program one time and called ```BCryptCloseAlgorithmProvider()``` in the end. I don't think it will be cached?

Comment: Sorry for my typo, not the ```BCRYPT_SHA256_ALGORITHM```. The correct is ```NCRYPT_ECDSA_P256_ALGORITHM```. I post my code, please take a look.

Comment: Add error message ```NTE_BAD_KEYSET``` in Q2, thanks

Comment: It seems to me that you've mainly got problems with the `NCryptSignHash` method, however exactly that code is missing.

Comment: #1 question Solved, it need add ```NCryptSetProperty()``` to set key length. I post my ```NCryptSignHash()``` code.

Comment: I have added **UPDATE2**